# how to send data to server in android

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I want to send latitude and longitude cyclically in my app.
This is the function which get this parameters using GPS

```
 private void showLocation(Location location) {
    String latitude = "Latitude: ";
    String longitude = "Longitude: ";

    if (location != null) {
        latitude += location.getLatitude();
        longitude += location.getLongitude();
}
}
```

I was looking methods in the web, I found some but it didn't work and it's deprecated

```
public void sendData(double latitude, double longitude){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.x.x.x:8080/run/mypage.php");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude", Double.toString(latitude)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", Double.toString(longitude)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your issue with obtaining the location or posting it to the server?

Comment: posting it to the server

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library for networking. Your example could be something like this

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient(); 

public String sendData(double latitude, double longitude){
    try {
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Latitude", Double.toString(latitude))
                .add("Longitude", Double.toString(longitude))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://httpbin.org/post")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to run networking code in an `AsyncTask`

```
class IOAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {
        return sendData(params[0].getLatitude(), params[0].getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        Log.d("networking", response);
    }
}
```

And this could be the `onCreate` method of your activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Location current = new Location("");
    current.setLatitude(23.9569596);
    current.setLongitude(12.567567);

    new IOAsyncTask().execute(current);
}
```

Please notice that I use `http://httpbin.org/post` as remote address, you must replace with your Endpoint URL. In my case the response is:

```
{
 "args": {}, 
 "data": "", 
 "files": {}, 
 "form": {
   "Latitude": "23.9569596", 
   "Longitude": "12.567567"
 }, 
 "headers": {
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip", 
   "Content-Length": "39", 
   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
   "Host": "httpbin.org", 
   "User-Agent": "okhttp/3.0.1"
 }, 
 "json": null, 
 "origin": "xxx.xx.xxx.xx", 
 "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for help, but I have another problem in line 
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()

android studio display that cannot resolve method 'FormBody'