# How does one go about sending login information to a server in c# for an android mobile app?

Tags: c#, android

The extent of my knowledge in coding is basic business applications in vb and c++. I understand very basic formatting and keywords. The most complicated thing i have ever made is a drink machine in c++. I have read some c# textbooks and I am still confused on how apps themselves send data to a server such as logging into an account on said server. What keywords would be used to do this, and what is the best way to learn about this? ELI5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send data to server in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323905/how-to-send-data-to-server-in-android)

Comment: if you are targeting .NET and android at the same time, take a look on `xamarin`. The communication between your android platform and your server is via `REST ` services. If you are not familiar of this one, then you should read. Keep in mind, that the common gateway between your client application and server side application is using RESTFUL SERVICES

Comment: Thank you so much!